# Fastest way to update a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, performance, hashtable

I have a dictionary A, and a possible entry foo. I know that A[foo] should be equal to x, but I don't know if A[foo] has been already defined. In any case if A[foo] has been defined it means that it already has the correct value.

It is faster to execute:

```
if foo not in A.keys(): 
   A[foo]=x
```

or simply update

```
A[foo]=x
```

because by the time the computer has found the foo entry, it can as well update it. While if not I would have to call the hash table two times?

Thanks.

Comment: How can you even have this problem? Normally you'd know which keys you've set before or simply build the final dict in one go.

Comment: I am calculating all the elements (and relations) in an Algebra. And I have to use what I know to find out the ones I don't know. Some calculations are harder, so I keep them for last. Hoping that by the time I go to calculate them, I can use the others to derive them for free. So soon I don't know anymore which relations I have already discovered and which I didn't. Since the elements are many, and the relations too, I need to be fast.

Comment: From the description of the problem, it seems as if dictionary storage will not be the major bottle-neck in your program.  Just write the clearest program you can write and if it's too slow, profile it and optimize where needed.  In my experience, I almost never get to to profile and optimize step.

Comment: When you used `timeit` what did you learn?  Please post the results.

Comment: @S.Lott  I just posted an answer using `timeit`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just add items to the dictionary without checking for their existence.  I added 100,000 items to a dictionary using 3 different methods and timed it with the timeit module.

1. `if k not in d: d[k] = v`
2. `d.setdefault(k, v)`
3. `d[k] = v`

Option 3 was the fastest, but not by much.

[ *Actually, I also tried `if k not in d.keys(): d[k] = v`, but that was slower by a factor of 300 (each iteration built a list of keys and performed a linear search).  It made my tests so slow that I left it out here.* ]

Here's my code:

```
import timeit

setup = """
import random
random.seed(0)
item_count = 100000
# divide key range by 5 to ensure lots of duplicates 
items = [(random.randint(0, item_count/5), 0) for i in xrange(item_count)]
"""
in_dict = """
d = {}
for k, v in items:
    if k not in d:
        d[k] = v
"""
set_default = """
d = {}
for k, v in items:
    d.setdefault(k, v)
"""
straight_add = """
d = {}
for k, v in items:
    d[k] = v
"""
print 'in_dict      ', timeit.Timer(in_dict, setup).timeit(1000)
print 'set_default  ', timeit.Timer(set_default, setup).timeit(1000)
print 'straight_add ', timeit.Timer(straight_add, setup).timeit(1000)
```

And the results:

```
in_dict       13.090878085
set_default   21.1309413091
straight_add  11.4781760635
```

**Note:** This is all pretty pointless.  We get many questions daily about what's the fastest way to do x or y in Python.  In most cases, it is clear that the question was being asked before any performance issues were encountered.  My advice?  Focus on writing the clearest program you can write and if it's too slow, profile it and optimize where needed. In my experience, I almost never get to to profile and optimize step.  From the description of the problem, it seems as if dictionary storage will not be the major bottle-neck in your program.

Comment: Thanks for testing it out. Now WE know. Yes, of course if I was "just" interested in speed for this one program I should have gone for profiling. But I am not. I don't know you, but to me I am often in the situation where I need to decide if re-writing a dict entry or checking before. It's a matter of mental cleanliness to just know which one is better. And two orders of magnitude are a lot!

Answer (score 15):

Using the built-in update() function is even faster. I tweaked Steven Rumbalski's example above a bit and it shows how update() is the fastest. There are at least two ways to use it (with a list of tuples or with another dictionary). The former (shown below as update_method1) is the fastest. Note that I also changed a couple of other things about Steven Rumbalski's example. My dictionaries will each have exactly 100,000 keys but the new values have a 10% chance of not needing to be updated. This chance of redundancy will depend on the nature of the data that you're updating your dictionary with. In all cases on my machine, my update_method1 was the fastest.

```
import timeit

setup = """
import random
random.seed(0)
item_count = 100000
existing_dict = dict([(str(i), random.randint(1, 10)) for i in xrange(item_count)])
items = [(str(i), random.randint(1, 10)) for i in xrange(item_count)]
items_dict = dict(items)
"""
in_dict = """
for k, v in items:
    if k not in existing_dict:
        existing_dict[k] = v
"""
set_default = """
for k, v in items:
    existing_dict.setdefault(k, v)
"""
straight_add = """
for k, v in items:
    existing_dict[k] = v
"""
update_method1 = """
existing_dict.update(items)
"""
update_method2 = """
existing_dict.update(items_dict)
"""
print 'in_dict        ', timeit.Timer(in_dict, setup).timeit(1000)
print 'set_default    ', timeit.Timer(set_default, setup).timeit(1000)
print 'straight_add   ', timeit.Timer(straight_add, setup).timeit(1000)
print 'update_method1 ', timeit.Timer(update_method1, setup).timeit(1000)
print 'update_method2 ', timeit.Timer(update_method2, setup).timeit(1000)
```

This code resulted in the following results:

```
in_dict         10.6597309113
set_default     19.3389420509
straight_add    11.5891621113
update_method1  7.52693581581
update_method2  9.10132408142
```

Answer (score 10):

```
if foo not in A.keys(): 
    A[foo] = x
```

is very slow, because `A.keys()` creates a list, which has to be parsed in O(N).

```
if foo not in A: 
    A[foo] = x
```

is faster, because it takes O(1) to check, whether `foo` exists in `A`.

```
A[foo] = x
```

is even better, because you already have the object `x` and you just add (if it already does not exist) a pointer to it to `A`.

Comment: Am I wrong :-/ ? I think the question was how to set an item to dict if it is not there already...

Comment: His question is written a little weird, but he is saying that 'if the value already is set, it was set correctly', so yeah, overwriting with the exact same value is fine in this case.

Comment: Hi Thomas, sorry, if I word it funny. Feel free to edit-correct it. But it seem to me that you got exactly what I meant :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are certainly faster ways than your first example. But I suspect the straight update will be faster than any test.

Answer (score 1):

```
foo not in A.keys()
```

will, in Python 2, create a new list with the keys and then perform linear search on it. This is guaranteed to be slower (although I mainly object to it because there are alternatives that are faster *and* more elegant/idiomatic).

```
A[foo] = x
```

and

```
if foo not in A:
    A[foo] = x
```

are different if `A[foo]` already exists but `is not x`. But since your "know" `A[foo]` will be `x`, it doesn't matter *semantically*. Anyway, both will be fine performance-wise (hard to tell without benchmarking, although intuitively I'd say the `if` takes much more time than copying a pointer).

So the answer is clear anyway: Choose the one that is **much** shorter code-wise and just as clear (the first one).

Answer (score 1):

If you "know" that A[foo] "should be" equal to x, then I would just do:

```
assert(A[foo]==x)
```

which will tell you if your assumption is wrong!

Comment: Although this will fail with a `KeyError` if `foo not in A`. But indeed, if the programs starts giving wrong results, use an `if foo in A: assert A[foo] == x`.

Comment: Thanks, this would not work. foo might be not defined without this being an error at all. Only if it is defined, I know it is equal to x. If I check, I might make more robust code (and in fact I do have those asserts for now) but slower. Eventually the code must work without those asserts.

Answer (score 0):

`A.setdefault(foo, x)` but i'm not sure it is faster then `if not A.has_key(foo): A[foo] = x`. Should be tested.

Comment: I was thinking about setdefault as well, but I doubt it's faster than `A[foo] = x`

Comment: It is not faster, but `A[foo]=x` doesn't do what the original author wants. According to the snippet `foo:x` is added when and only when the dict doesn't have a key foo.

Comment: Thanks khachik, the op (me) just need to make sure that by the end A[foo]=x. If it was already defined and a[foo] was already equal to x I am ok to reassign it if it's faster.

Comment: @Pietro to make sure: I just tested, `A[foo]=x` is faster (1/1.5) then `A.setdefault(foo, x)`. So you can just reassign, if the old value can be overridden.